# how to display table on android with enabled scrolling

Tags: android, csv, scroll, tableview

I'm working on an application for android, where users can upload their csv files.
ofcourse csv files can have lots of rows and/or columns, so my problem is how to display all that data within android table.
i would like to know how to do that and enable scrolling in both horizontal and vertical direction, so the whole table can be viewed?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a table, just put it inside a ScrollView.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Anyway, I don't know if using a table is the best option. I think tables in Android should be deprecated already.

Comment: thanks for quick response. i tried scrollview, but it only scrolls vertically, multiple columns is still problem.
what do you suggest to use instead of tablelayout?

Comment: Well ... the only awesome app that does vertical and horizontal scrolling is Google Sheets. Anyway ... I'm sure that there is not easy way to do that. Probably they created a new view only for that app.